# Django: Can't access cleaned_data even after calling .is_valid

Tags: python, django

I started trying to clean up some of my code, and, when testing, I kept running into this bug:`'log_in' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'` As a bit of background, the code checks which of two forms is being submitted (`log_in_is_new_form()`) and then goes through some validation such as checking that it is an email address at a certain host. It returns html objects that give instructions to the javascript that calls the page on what to do (such as show the other form or show the errors). It's a very simple ajax without JSON because the site is very small and very low traffic (100 users at most a day. That being unlikely)

```
def log_in_pass_match(form):
    cleaned = form.cleaned_data
    if cleaned['password'] == cleaned['password2']:
        return true
    else:
        return false

def log_in_is_bbn(form):
    email_bbn = form.cleaned_data['username'].split("@")
    if 'bbns.org' in email_bbn:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def log_in_is_new_form( post):
    if "TN" in post:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def log_in_already_user(form):
    form.is_valid
    user_object = User.objects.filter(email = form.cleaned_data['username'])
    if user_object.exists():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def log_in_send_act(form):
    cleaned = form.cleaned_data['username']
    msg = "sfsd"
    send_mail('Activate', msg, 'michaelrgoldfine@gmail.com', [cleaned['username']], fail_silently=False)
    new_user_object = User.objects.create_user(
        username=cleaned_info_new['username'],
        password=cleaned_info_new['password'],
        email=cleaned_info_new['username']
    )


def user_log_in(request):
    error = []
    form = log_in(request.POST)
    if not log_in_already_user(form):
        form = new_user(request.POST)
        if log_in_is_new_form():
            form_is_valid = True
            other_is_valid = True
            if form.is_valid():
                if log_in_is_bbn(form = form) and log_in_pass_match(form = form):
                    other_is_valid = True
                else:
                    other_is_valid = False
            else:
                form_is_valid = False

            if form_is_valid and other_is_valid:
                msg = "In order to activate your account at Knights of the Round Table, please click on this link:"
                try:
                    user_object = User.objects.create_user(
                        username=cleaned_info_new['username'],
                        password=cleaned_info_new['password'],
                        email=cleaned_info_new['username']
                    )
                    log_in_send_act(form = form)
                    new_user_profile = user_object.get_profile()
                    new_user_profile.pen_name = form.cleaned_data['pen_name']
                    new_user_profile.activated = False;
                    new_user_profile.save()
                    return HttpResponse("not_act")
                except:
                    error.append("Error Sending Email")
            else:
                if not other_is_valid and log_in_is_new_form(request.POST):
                    if log_in_is_bbn(form = form):
                        error.append('BBN email addresses only: [first initial][last name]@bbns.org.')
                    if log_in_pass_match(form = form):
                        error.append('Passwords do not match')
                for n in form._errors:
                    for e in form._errors[n]:
                        error.append(e)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("n_usr")
    else:
        if form.is_valid():
            if log_in_already_user():
                logged_in_user = auth.authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
                if loged_in_user is not None:
                    if user_object[0].get_profile().activated:
                        auth.login(request, logged_in_user)
                        return HttpResponseRedirect("")
                    else:
                        return HttpResponse("not_act")
                else:
                    error.append('Password Incorrect')
    errors_template = Template("{% for e in errors %}<li>{{ e }}</li> {% endfor %}")
    errors_html = errors_template.render(Context({'errors':error}))
    return HttpResponse(errors_html)
```

Full error:

```
AttributeError at /ajax/login
'log_in' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/login
Django Version: 1.4
Python Executable: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path: ['/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
Server time: Tue, 7 Aug 2012 19:11:39 -0400
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'Knights',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN/Knights/views.py" in user_log_in
  68.     if not log_in_already_user(form):
File "/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN/Knights/views.py" in log_in_already_user
  48.     user_object = User.objects.filter(email = form.cleaned_data['username'])

Exception Type: AttributeError at /ajax/login
Exception Value: 'log_in' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
Request information:
GET: No GET data

POST:
username = u''
password = u'Password'

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES:
csrftoken = 'Df1jB3708JUgretV8PSmRQ6NFQGI3wzL'
sessionid = 'c5eab78e2c73ff493056044d4e4362ba'

META:
RUN_MAIN = 'true'
HTTP_REFERER = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/'
SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE = 'WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3'
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '309'
REQUEST_METHOD = 'POST'
LOGNAME = 'Mike'
USER = 'Mike'
HTTP_ORIGIN = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
PATH = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin'
QUERY_STRING = ''
HOME = '/Users/Mike'
wsgi.errors = <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x100284270>
TERM_PROGRAM = 'Apple_Terminal'
LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET = 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
TERM = 'xterm-256color'
SHELL = '/bin/bash'
TZ = 'America/New_York'
HTTP_COOKIE = 'csrftoken=Df1jB3708JUgretV8PSmRQ6NFQGI3wzL; sessionid=c5eab78e2c73ff493056044d4e4362ba'
SERVER_NAME = '1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
REMOTE_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
SHLVL = '1'
wsgi.url_scheme = 'http'
_ = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python'
SERVER_PORT = '8000'
PATH_INFO = u'/ajax/login'
CONTENT_LENGTH = '27'
TERM_SESSION_ID = '37C63610-0B15-480A-A5C3-1619ECABE279'
HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH = 'XMLHttpRequest'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/launch-elZmdg/Listeners'
wsgi.input = <socket._fileobject object at 0x101bd6550>
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render = '/tmp/launch-nMejuv/Render'
HTTP_HOST = '127.0.0.1:8000'
SCRIPT_NAME = u''
wsgi.multithread = True
HTTP_CONNECTION = 'keep-alive'
TMPDIR = '/var/folders/98/m4rlvgtx0d19gbmh824m8jt80000gn/T/'
HTTP_ACCEPT = '*/*'
wsgi.version = 
HTTP_USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.57 Safari/537.1'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = 'CGI/1.1'
wsgi.run_once = False
OLDPWD = '/Users/Mike'
wsgi.multiprocess = False
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = '0x1F5:0:0'
Apple_Ubiquity_Message = '/tmp/launch-8Ck6J2/Apple_Ubiquity_Message'
PWD = '/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'BBN.settings'
CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
wsgi.file_wrapper = ''
REMOTE_HOST = ''
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = 'gzip,deflate,sdch'
COMMAND_MODE = 'unix2003'

Settings:
Using settings module BBN.settings
USE_L10N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'BBN.urls'
MANAGERS = 
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Django] '
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = None
URL_VALIDATOR_USER_AGENT = 'Django/1.4 (https://www.djangoproject.com)'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = 
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
ADMIN_FOR = 
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = 
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'TEST_MIRROR': None, 'NAME': 'database', 'TEST_CHARSET': None, 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'TEST_COLLATION': None, 'PORT': '', 'HOST': '', 'USER': '', 'TEST_NAME': None, 'PASSWORD': u'********************', 'OPTIONS': {}}}
SERVER_EMAIL = 'root@localhost'
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = 
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/html'
APPEND_SLASH = True
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 0
DATABASE_ROUTERS = []
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
CACHES = {'default': {'LOCATION': '', 'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = 
USE_I18N = True
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ','
SECRET_KEY = u'********************'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'django_language'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE = ''
TRANSACTIONS_MANAGED = False
LOGGING_CONFIG = 'django.utils.log.dictConfig'
SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS = False
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = 
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'BBN.wsgi.application'
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = None
CACHE_BACKEND = 'locmem://'
SIGNING_BACKEND = 'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
DEBUG = True
SESSION_FILE_PATH = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
INSTALLED_APPS = 
LANGUAGES = 
COMMENTS_ALLOW_PROFANITIES = False
STATICFILES_DIRS = 
PREPEND_WWW = False
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = None
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'Knights.UserInfo'
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = False
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'F j'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
TIME_FORMAT = 'P'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = 
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = u'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS = u'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False
NUMBER_GROUPING = 0
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile/'
LOGGING = {'loggers': {'django.request': {'handlers': ['mail_admins'], 'propagate': True, 'level': 'ERROR'}}, 'version': 1, 'disable_existing_loggers': False, 'filters': {'require_debug_false': {'()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'}}, 'handlers': {'mail_admins': {'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler', 'filters': ['require_debug_false'], 'level': 'ERROR'}}}
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = 
LOCALE_PATHS = 
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = ''
LOGOUT_URL = '/accounts/logout/'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
FIXTURE_DIRS = 
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j, Y'
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER = 'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
ADMINS = 
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = None
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'
MEDIA_URL = ''
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'N j, Y, P'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = '/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN/Knights/templates'
SITE_ID = 1
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = 
ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS = 
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.simple.DjangoTestSuiteRunner'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = u'********************'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE = ''
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = 
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600
SETTINGS_MODULE = 'BBN.settings'
USE_ETAGS = False
LANGUAGES_BIDI = 
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = None
INTERNAL_IPS = 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
USE_TZ = True
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y P'
PASSWORD_HASHERS = u'********************'
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 600
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*****@gmail.com'
PROFANITIES_LIST = u'********************'

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your
Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will
display a standard 500 page.
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but why are you using `&` instead of `and` in your if statement.

Comment: @mVChr Not the issue, but thanks

Comment: Why are you checking passwords match in a separate function, rather than doing it in the form's `clean` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually calling `is_valid` here:

```
form.is_valid # missing the call ()
```